# iptables stupid error (iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT)

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables

```
[root@router ~]# iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

How is that possible? I recompiled the kernel (3.11.8) and updated iptables to 1.4.16. The strage thing is that if I manually put the above rule in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and I issue the command `/etc/init.d/iptables restart` (I'm on CentOS 6.4) it works! It inserts the rule.

My `lsmod | grep ipt`:

```
iptable_mangle         12695  1 
ipt_MASQUERADE         12759  3 
iptable_nat            12810  1 
nf_nat_ipv4            13263  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 25997  3 ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat,nf_nat_ipv4
nf_conntrack           95633  7 xt_state,ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,xt_conntrack
iptable_filter         12810  1 
ip_tables              27213  3 iptable_mangle,iptable_nat,iptable_filter
```

`iptables -L` output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: What's the output of iptables -L ?

Comment: Added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Basically I did a `make uninstall` of the iptables 1.4.16 version and compiled from source the 1.4.20 version (latest available now). Now it works perfectly.